# Primeng PanelMenu renders nested duplicates

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-menu

Tried on rendering PanelMenu, which has nested navigation item inside nested navigation item. Found out, that the panel renders duplicate items which doesn't meet written navigation structure. For instance, here is the snippet of how the structure looks like:

```
export const sidebarMenu: MenuItem[] = [
  {
    label: 'Packages',
    icon: '',
    styleClass: '',
    url: '/packages',
    target: '_self',
  },
  {
    label: 'Documents',
    icon: '',
    styleClass: '',
    items: [
      {
        label: 'A',
        icon: '',
        url: '/a',
      },
      {
        label: 'B',
        icon: '',
        url: '/b',
      },
    ],
    target: '_self',
  },
  {
    label: 'Logout',
    icon: '',
    styleClass: '',
    url: '/',
    target: '_self',
  },
];
```

And the render is simple:

```
 <p-panelMenu styleClass="h-16 w-full bg-grey" [model]="items"> </p-panelMenu>
```

However, from what I see, when I open Documents Item, it appears to render one more sidebarMenu structure. Providing image for better understanding.

[image: Image of nested navigation]

Cannot find out of why duplicate navigation render happens.

Comment: please replicate the issue in a stackblitz and share back! [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-panelmenu-demo-c32yc4)